# Rotate camera axis by mouse - Open GL

Tags: vb.net, opengl, matrix, rotation

So I have successfully managed to rotate, move, etc with keyboard keys my camera through my environment. I do this by multiplying my view matrix by rotational matrices:

```
ViewMatrix = ViewMatrix X Z_Rotational_Matrix(yaw_increment) X X_Rotational_Matrix(pitch_increment) X Y_Rotational_Matrix(roll_increment)
```

I can do so with inputs of yaw, pitch, and roll. So I am next trying to do these rotations with the mouse. I believe I have all of the heavy lifting done and should just need to supply the yaw, and pitch to my rotational matrix. Correct me if this is the wrong thought process.

I can capture the mouse world coordinate when I click and when I move so supposedly it should just be math based on *initial_mouse_click_coordinates* and *current_mouse_click_coordinates*.  My thought is to project two vectors, one from the initial_mouse_click_coordinate and the other from current_mouse_click_coordinates. Both vectors are parallel to the vector created from my camera location and my camera lookat point. Then I can calculate the XY planar angle and the XZ planar angle. Once these are determined I pass these as the yaw and pitch to my rotational matrices.

**Determining two angles between my two lines:**

[image]

The problem I have is that these values appear to be really small so on the screen nothing really happens.  Am I going about this the wrong way completely?

If this is the right method to try, am I messing up on my math somewhere?

```
'we have initial_mouse_world_coordinates and mouse_world_coordinates. These are the points on the x screen in world coordinates.
    'Two lines must be constructed going through these points, parallel with our lookat vector. 
    'The two angles between these two vectors are the angles to use on our lookat vector

    'X = X0 + Rx*T
    'Y = Y0 + Ry*T
    'Z = Z0 + Rz*T

    'therefore T = (Z-Z0)/Rz
    'at Z = 0: T = -Z0/Rz
    Dim t As Decimal = -initial_mouse_world_coordinates.Z / cam.lookat.Z
    Dim y As Decimal = initial_mouse_world_coordinates.Y + (cam.lookat.Y * t)
    Dim x As Decimal = initial_mouse_world_coordinates.X + (cam.lookat.X * t)
    Dim z As Decimal = 0

    'new point = x,y,z => translate to new vector

    Dim startline As New Vector3(initial_mouse_world_coordinates.X - x, initial_mouse_world_coordinates.Y - y, initial_mouse_world_coordinates.Z - z)

    t = -mouse_world_coordinates.Z / cam.lookat.Z
    y = mouse_world_coordinates.Y + (cam.lookat.Y * t)
    x = mouse_world_coordinates.X + (cam.lookat.X * t)
    z = 0

    Dim endline As New Vector3(mouse_world_coordinates.X - x, mouse_world_coordinates.Y - y, mouse_world_coordinates.Z - z)



    'now simply find the two angles between these two lines

    'cos(theida) = ((Ai,Ak) ⋅ (Bi,Bk)) / (||Ai,Ak|| * ||Bi,Bk||)
    Try
        theida = Acos(((startline.X * endline.X) + (startline.Z * endline.Z)) / (Sqrt(startline.X ^ 2 + startline.Z ^ 2) * Sqrt(endline.X ^ 2 + endline.Z ^ 2)))
    Catch
        theida = 0
    End Try
    Try
        phi = Acos(((startline.X * endline.X) + (startline.Y * endline.Y)) / (Sqrt(startline.X ^ 2 + startline.Y ^ 2) * Sqrt(endline.X ^ 2 + endline.Y ^ 2)))
    Catch
        phi = 0
    End Try

    theida = theida * (180 / PI)
    phi = phi * (180 / PI)
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Again I may be going at this with the wrong idea in the first place.

Comment: Instead of using mouse clicks, it'd feel much more natural if you use a key + mouse movement. That way you would only have to check whether you have to rotate clockwise or counter clock wise by checking the sign and rotate by a fixed amount somewhat like in games.

Comment: what do you mean by  "My thought is to project two vectors", you only have the location of the 2 points on your screen. If you are using an ortho projection you may cast ray which are parralel to look at vector

Comment: @DraykoonD Well I can create the two vectors from those two points, making them parallel with my lookat vector. That is how I get two

Comment: I start to understand what you are doing, you are sure you want to use 2 parralel vectors and not the 2 line between your mouseCoord and cameraLookatPoint. the angle between the 2 should represent the rotation you are hopping for. Your mouseCoord.z should be near plane i suppose.

Comment: Like you see on your scheme the 2 vector you got on each plane are close from being parrallel again so your resulting angle is low.

Comment: @DraykoonD What you are saying is true IF there is no roll on the screen (my up vector parallel to the Z axis) but what you are saying is not true if rolled some

Comment: what is your t value for each of your vector, it should be the same ? mouseCoord.z == initialCoord.z